# Cloud Run Setting Backups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I inherited a GCP environment with several Cloud Run services already deployed that are no longer needed. I'd like to take a backup of all the settings and various artifacts associated with each before I kill them, just in case, but I can't find the appropriate docs.

Anybody know of an easy way to capture everything?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to backup all the settings and various artifacts because cloud run is serverless.

You may file a feature request in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

**Note**: There's no ETA for it but you can track the progress once the Product Team validated on it.

Comment: Thanks. I have all the code needed to recreate the underlying containers, but is there a way to even save the various settings needed to recreate the Cloud Run jobs as they currently are? Or am I stuck with something like manually recording or taking screenshots of the GCP console or something?